# Convert mm/dd/yy to mm/dd/yyyy in PHP

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm working on a project that requires me to read values from a file and manipulate them slightly before storing them elsewhere. One of the things I need to do is convert some dates from mm/dd/yy format to mm/dd/yyyy format. Unfortunately for me, I am relatively new to PHP and regular expressions (which I assume is one of the better ways to solve this problem), and am therefore somewhat mystified. Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A four-digit year can represent 10,000 possibilities.  A two-digit year can only handle 100 possibilities.  What does '20' mean?  Is that 1920 or 2020?  Or maybe it's 8720?

Comment: @Borealid: That is the same problem that has PHP, which accepts dates like `12/22/78`. The problem is usually resolved setting a value `L` that is compared with the two digits year `yy`; if `yy` is greater than `L`, then the four digits year is `19yy`; otherwise the four digits year is `20yy'.

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a [built-in function `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) that is meant for just this kind of task... it'll even do the best-guess for the 2-digit year following this rule: *the values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999*. Once you have the date/time in the UNIXy format that PHP prefers, then you can print it out however you want with the [`date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
<?php
$str = '02/28/98';

// in PHP 5.1.0+, strtotime() returns false if it fails
// previous to PHP 5.1.0, you would compare with -1 instead of false
if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) {
    echo "Couldn't figure out the date ($str)!";
} else {
    echo "Reformatted date is " . date('m/d/Y', $timestamp);
}
?>
```

(I presume we're timezone-agnostic here, or that would add complications.)

Comment: don't you mean date('MM/DD/Y'....? OP wants to go from YY to YYYY ... one Y is the four digit year.

Comment: and I mean 'm/d/Y' in the very last line (can't edit my previous comment). Lower case m and d keep the leading zeros.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai -- yes, you're totally right. (I should have tried it to confirm before posting!) I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, it may or may not work:

```
$new_date = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime( $old_date ) );
```

Where `$old_date` is in the format you're talking about.

Comment: If the date is in the format `mm-dd-yy` this code will not work. so we have to convert the `mm-dd-yy` to `mm/dd/yy` by replcaing the `-` by `/`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems here is that `YY`, assuming it is relatively current, can be either 19YY or 20YY. This means you should pick a number to be the cut off. Let's call this `$cutOff` If YY is less than `$cutOff`, we want `20YY` if greater than we want `19YY`

You could do it with regex, but since your example is simple and regex tends to be slower, you can simply use string manipulation with [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [substr_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

Here's how to change a string mm/dd/yy int mm/dd/yyyy:

```
<?php
// Our date
$str = "01/04/10";
$cutoff = 50;
// See what YY is
// Get the substring of $str starting two from the end (-2)... this is YY
$year = substr($str, -2);
// Check whether year added should be 19 or 20
if ($year < 50)
    // PHP converts string to number nicely, so this is our 20YY
    $year += 2000;
else
    // This is 19YY
    $year += 1900;
// Repace YY with YYYY
// This will take $str and replace the part two from the end (-2) undtil 
// the end with $year.
$str = substr_replace($str, $year, -2);  
// See what we got
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Great explanation, and this tactic is quite necessary if `strtotimes()`'s use of "70" as the pivot year... or if you have dates *before* 1970, because they don't fit in the UNIX seconds-elapsed-since-the-epoch dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the year starting two values (19 or 20) as below:

```
//for $s_date = "yy-dd-mm"
if (substr($s_date,6,2) >= 50){
    $standarddate  = "19" . substr($s_date,6,2); //19yy
    $standarddate .= "-"  . substr($s_date,0,2); //mm
    $standarddate .= "-"  . substr($s_date,3,2); //dd
} else {
    $standarddate  = "20" . substr($s_date,6,2); //20yy
    $standarddate .= "-"  . substr($s_date,0,2); //mm
    $standarddate .= "-"  . substr($s_date,3,2); //dd
}
// you will get yyyy-mm-dd
```